# BAT/CMD file to assign drive letter IF condition is met using DISKPART

Tags: batch-file

My programming skills are very weak and I'm trying to modify this script below that I got it from here.

The script should look into the header Fs and IF "unKno" is found then assign Letter=B

I know their are other ways you can point to a text file with the diskpart command but I would like to avoid that. I would like (if possible) to have it done without using texts files.

Is this possible?

```html
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^
        echo list volume ^|^
        diskpart ^|^
        findstr Volume ^|^
        findstr /v ^
        /c:"Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info"^
       ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        set letter=!line:~15,1!
        set fs=!line:~32,5!
        if not "Unkno"=="!fs!" (
            if not " "=="!letter!" (
                call :removeVol !letter!
            )
        )
    )
endlocal
exit /b

:removeVol
    (
        echo select volume %1
        echo assign letter=B %1
    ) | diskpart
exit /b​
```

Source:
[BAT/CMD file to remove drive letters using DISKPART](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024985/bat-cmd-file-to-remove-drive-letters-using-diskpart)